# How do I prevent a deadlock?

Tags: c, linux, process, synchronization, signals

I've been struggling with a synchronization problem for a while. I've got a process A, this is the main one, and 3 processes of type B. These processes have to signal A and wait for response.

A is waiting for all 3 signals. When they all arrive, A does it's job and signals all B processes back so they can continue their work.

```
A:
   if(/*all signals received*/)  {
     //do my job
     //signal all Bs
   }

B:
   //some code
   signal(A);
   pause();  //wait for response
   //Do other stuff
```

When B calls `signal(A)`, A does his job, signals B back, then schedules B again causing B to call `pause()` and wait for a signal indefinitely. I don't know how to prevent this deadlock.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Are your `signal` calls blocking? Meaning, when a process of type B calls `signal(A)`, will B _wait_ until A signals something back?

Comment: signal should be asynchronous, just send the message and continue execution. That's why I tried to call pause() right after that. If this is what you mean...

Comment: Oh, I forget to mention, it's written on Unix-like systems... so it's using unix signals...

Comment: Yeap. That's what I meant. Also, when a process of type B executes a `pause`, does it wake up on receiving some signal?

Comment: If I send any random signal, yes... But the signal from A I need to react is already lost...

Comment: I personally think signals are a very bad choice in this case. Why not use mutexes or semaphores instead?

Comment: Do you have to use signals?  Standard signals are not queued so if 3 sub process are sending the same signal there is a pretty good chance some are going to be thrown away.  Process A will never increment its ctr and deadlock.  You could try posix realtime signals or (much) better yet use another mechanism like semaphores.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using semaphore as IPC synchronization,
any process want to send signal have to lock the semaphore,
and after receiveing A's return, unlocking it so next process can proceed.

Comment: It isn't as simple as this. Semaphores can only be used by _related_ processes for synchronization. To do that, you'd have to use shared memory or some such concept.

Comment: There are process semaphores(System V semaphores) that doesn't limit to related processes. Also, even you want to do that using shared memory, you also need semaphore to synchronize.

Comment: If OP need some good books, I recommand "Advanced Linux Programming", Chapter 5 explains various IPC and synchronization.

Comment: System V semaphores are much slower.

Comment: POSIX likewise has named semaphores for unrelated processes.